# Which C functions are not gil-requiring in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

I try to compile the following `Cython` code, which uses `C` functions for file operations:

```
import tempfile
from libc.stdio cimport *

cdef extern from "stdio.h":
    FILE *fopen(const char *, const char *)
    int fclose(FILE *)
    size_t fwrite(const void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *)
    ssize_t getline(char **, size_t *, FILE *)

def run_io():
    cdef int ntasks
    cdef int i
    cdef string dump = "Some string"
    cdef string content = ""
    cdef char* fname
    cdef FILE* cfile
    cdef char* line = NULL
    cdef size_t l = 0
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+')
    fname = tmpfile.name.encode("UTF-8")
    with nogil:
        cfile = fopen(fname, "wb")
        #fwrite(dump.data(), 1, dump.size(), cfile)
        #fclose(cfile)
        #cfile = fopen(fname, "rb")
        #if getline(&line, &l, cfile) == -1:
            #break
        #else:
            #printf("%s", line)
        fclose(cfile)
    tmpfile.close()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        #cfile = fopen(fname, "rb")
        #if getline(&line, &l, cfile) == -1:
            #break
        #else:
            #printf("%s", line)
        fclose(cfile)
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:31:14: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil
```

I thought that only `python` functions are gil-requiring but not imported `C` ones. Nevertheless, it seems like it is not so.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Which C functions can be used in `Cython` without `GIL`?
2. How to make file read/write without `GIL`?

Comment: Going to hazard a guess that the problem is `printf` since you haven't defined it properly (no mention in the extern block).

Comment: @Dunes I commented it out and got the same result

Comment: A separate issue to your GIL problem, but: you should use `printf("%s",line)` instead of `printf(line)`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Comment: Second guess. Are you sure you can use `break` with a `with` statement in cython? In python that is not allowed. The compiler may have emitted a python break as there is no loop construct, and python break would not be allowed in a `with nogil` block.

Comment: Your code has multiple issues, and converting it with cython yields multiple errors. Provide something that reproduces __only__ the problem you have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are shadowing the declarations from `libc.stdio` which are declared with

```
cdef extern from "stdio.h" nogil:
```

with your own definitions which do not have `nogil`. To answer the question in your title: only Python/C API functions require the gil.

This is your code with correct imports and trimmed of anything not relevant:

```
import tempfile
from libc.stdio cimport fopen, fclose, fwrite, getline, FILE
from libcpp.string cimport string

def run_io():
    cdef string dump = b"Some string"
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+')
    cdef bytes py_fname = tmpfile.name.encode("UTF-8")
    cdef char* fname = py_fname
    cdef FILE* cfile
    with nogil:
        cfile = fopen(fname, "wb")
        fclose(cfile)
    tmpfile.close()
```

The following is necessary to ensure that the lifetime of the **temporary** returned by `tmpfile.name.encode` is extended.

```
cdef bytes py_fname = tmpfile.name.encode("UTF-8")
cdef char* fname = py_fname
```

It gives no errors when compiled with

```
cython -3 --cplus my_mod.pyx
g++ my_mod.cpp -shared -o my_mod.so $(python3.4 --cflags --ldflags)
```